# Matlab: Using fft without fftshift

Tags: matlab, fft

I have a simple question on using fft in 1D without using fftshift. Say I have a code running the fft of sin(6*2*pi*n):

```
n=0:1/20:1-1/20;
x=sin(2*pi*n);
X=fft(x);
plot(abs(X));
plot(abs(fftshift(X)));
```

Without fft shift, I see a peak at 6Hz, and another peak at very very high frequency like 2000Hz.  Does this 2000Hz component coresponds to the -6Hz peak?

Comment: "A very very high frequency" - you haven't told us what the sampling frequency is here.

Comment: The sampling frequency is 20

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Typically the output of the FFT algorithm has the negative frequencies shifted to the second half of the positive frequenies, so if one directly graphs the fft output a negative peak that's very close to zero will appear as a positive peak very close to the right hand edge of a figure.  fftshift shifts the negatives to where one would intuitively expect them to be.